# Join tables based on date and min condition

Tags: sql, oracle, date, join, between

I have 2 tables, one of witch contains a single date column along other columns, the second table contains a startdate, enddate and foreign key column.

table a

```
ID | DATE       | COL1 | COL2
1  | 12.01.2018 | X    | Y
2  | 12.02.2018 | Z    | Y
3  | 12.03.2018 | Y    | A
4  | 12.04.2018 | B    | A
n  | ...        | ...  | ...
```

table b

```
ID | startDATE  | endDate    | fID
1  | 01.01.2018 | 31.01.2018 | 1
2  | 04.01.2018 | 15.01.2018 | 2
3  | 01.02.2018 | 28.02.2018 | 1
4  | 01.04.2018 | 30.04.2018 | 1
5  | 13.04.2018 | 20.04.2018 | 2
n  | ...        | ...        | ...
```

`table a` contains around +150 000 entries `table b` around +6000

I want to query the `ID` of `table a` and the minimum value of `fID` in `table b` if existend.

What i have so far is

```
SELECT
     a.ID
    ,nvl(min(b.fID),3)
FROM
    a
    LEFT JOIN b ON a.date between b.startDate AND b.endDate  
GROUP BY 
    a.ID
```

this works just as expected but the performace is poor, it takes around 45 seconds for the query to resolve. Is there any way to boost this? changing `group by` with `partition by` on the second select value results in the same length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be faster with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT a.ID,
       (SELECT COALESCE(MIN(b.fid), 3)
        FROM b
        WHERE a.date between b.startDate AND b.endDate
       )
FROM a;
```

The challenge is that it is hard to provide an index for the `WHERE` clause.